# How to create a matrix that is the sum of multiple matrices using pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have multiple data frames that I saved in a concatenated list like below. Each df represents a matrix.

```
my_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, .....])
```

How do I sum all these dfs (matrices) into one df (matrix)?

I found a [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106823/adding-two-pandas-dataframes), but it only answers how to add two data frames, by using code like below.

```
df_x.add(df_y, fill_value=0)
```

Should I use the code above in a loop, or is there a more concise way?

I tried to do `print(my_df.sum())` but got a very confusing result (it's suddenly turned into a one row instead of two-dimensional matrix).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `sum` with a list of arrays. The output here will be an array rather than a dataframe.

This assumes you need to replace `np.nan` with 0:

```
res = sum([x.fillna(0).values for x in [df1, df2, df3]])
```

Alternatively, you can use `numpy` directly in a couple of different ways:

```
res_np1 = np.add.reduce([x.fillna(0).values for x in [df1, df2, df3]])

res_np2 = np.nansum([x.values for x in [df1, df2, df3]], axis=0)
```

[`numpy.nansum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) assumes `np.nan` equals zero for summing purposes.

Comment: My data are integers (and none of them are nan, so it gets an error). Should I still use the `fillna(0)` part if there's no nan?

Comment: @AnnaRG, In this case, it's not necessary to use `fillna` or `nansum`. I recommend `np.sum([x.values for x in [df1, df2, df3]], axis=0)` for readability.

Comment: Thanks. So, your answer doesn't require the dfs to be concatenated first, unlike @ayhan answer. May I know, why is it so?

Comment: My answer drops down to `numpy`, while ayhan's answer sticks to `pandas`. There is more than one solution to this problem. If performance is not an issue, *use what makes most sense to you*.

Comment: I will, thanks. Out of curiosity, performance-wise, which should be the fastest solution?

Comment: @AnnaRG, I expect a `numpy` solution to be fastest. But you should test this with your data.

Answer (score 2):

I believe need [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) if each `DataFrame` in `list` have same index and columns values:

```
np.random.seed(2018)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,np.nan,2], size=(3,3)), columns=list('abc'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,np.nan,3], size=(3,3)), columns=list('abc'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,np.nan,4], size=(3,3)), columns=list('abc'))
print (df1)
     a    b    c
0  2.0  2.0  2.0
1  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  1.0  2.0  NaN

print (df2)
     a    b    c
0  NaN  NaN  1.0
1  3.0  3.0  3.0
2  NaN  1.0  3.0

print (df3)
     a    b    c
0  4.0  NaN  NaN
1  4.0  1.0  1.0
2  4.0  NaN  1.0

from functools import reduce

my_df = [df1,df2, df3]

df = reduce(lambda x, y: x.add(y, fill_value=0), my_df)
print (df)
     a    b    c
0  6.0  2.0  3.0
1  7.0  4.0  5.0
2  5.0  3.0  4.0
```

Comment: Interesting, never heard about `reduce`. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I believe the idiomatic solution to this is to preserve the information about different DataFrames with the help of the `keys` parameter and then use sum on the innermost level:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
my_df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=['df{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(len(dfs))])
my_df.sum(level=1)
```

which yields

```
     a    b    c
0  6.0  2.0  3.0
1  7.0  4.0  5.0
2  5.0  3.0  4.0
```

with jezrael's sample DataFrames.