# sum and append input of 2 files using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, append

I imported 2 file texts and I want to sum and append the results of both files like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Desktop\\line format.txt', sep="\t", header=None)
X2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Desktop\\line format2.txt', sep="\t", header=None)

print('X is : ',X)
print('X2 is : ',X2)
```

Results are like this :

```
X is :         0
0  1 2 3
1  4 5 6

X2 is :            0
0   7  8  9
1  10 11 12
2  13 14 15
```

what I want to do is to append like this

```
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9
10 11 12
13 14 15
```

and to sum like this

```
 8 10 12
14 16 18
```

Any help would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: For the first part, `pd.concat()`. For the summation question, how are you arriving at those sums?

Comment: thank you sum by rows forget about the third line in the second file

Comment: what is that `0` after `X is:....`

Comment: `pd.concat((X,X2)).groupby(level=0).sum()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang That's the first line of printing the dataframe.

Comment: figured out about the append thank you but still need the sum

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106823/adding-two-pandas-dataframes

Comment: not working giving me :                                                                             
`df_add is :                                                     0
0                     0
0       7 8 9,4 1 9,
1  1...`

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're aiming to add the same `indexes` from separate `df's`. Does this suit your needs? I don't understand `index 2` in `X2` though? Is it to be dropped if the same `index` doesn't exist in `X`?

```
import pandas as pd

X = ({
    'A' :    [1,4],
    'B' :    [2,5],
    'C' :    [3,6],
})

X = pd.DataFrame(data=X)

X2 = ({
    'A' :    [7,10,13],
    'B' :    [8,11,14],
    'C' :    [9,12,15],
})

X2 = pd.DataFrame(data=X2)

df_add = X.add(X2, fill_value=0)

print(df_add)

      A     B     C
0   8.0  10.0  12.0
1  14.0  16.0  18.0
2  13.0  14.0  15.0
```