# How to sum columns from two different size datasets in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have two datasets. The first one (df1) contains more then 200.000 rows, and the second one (df2) only two. I need to create a new column  df1['column_2'] which is the sum of df1['column_1'] and df2['column_1']

When I try to make df1['column_2'] = df1['column_1'] + df2['column_1'] I get an error "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

How can I sum values of different datasets with different amount of rows?
Will be thankful for any help!
Screenshot of my notebook: https://prnt.sc/p1d6ze

Comment: What do you mean by *sum of df1['column_1'] and df2['column_1']*? What do you expect the first item on `df1['column_2']` to be?

Comment: Please show sample data and code.

Comment: Unfourtunately, I can not add a screenshot, I need at least 10 reputation... 
I'll try to explain. I have a big dataset with clients. This dataframe has a column 'minutes_on_month' - total amount of minutes, which the clien spent during a month. The second dataframe has the describtion of tariff in the column 'minutes_included' it`s value, for example, 500. In fact I need to count extra_minutes for evety client

Comment: Redirecting to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106823/adding-two-pandas-dataframes. You can refer the reindex function of pandas.

Comment: @Stas but then, do you need to align the client's by the tariff before substracting? That is, clients `A,B,C` with tariff `x` should be subtracted by `m(x)` minutes, while clients `D,E` with tariff `y` should be subtracted by `m(y)`?

Comment: This is a slice from common table. In df_1 all clients use one tariff.

Comment: @LovleenKaur, and what about subtraction and other math actions?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works **with no error**, using *Pandas 0.25.0*
and *Python 3.7.0*.
If you use older versions, consider upgrade.

For the test I used *df1* with 10 rows (shorter):

```
   column_1
0        10
1        20
2        30
3        40
4        50
5        60
6        70
7        80
8        90
9       100
```

and *df2* with 2 rows (just as in your post):

```
   column_1
0         3
1         5
```

Your instruction `df1['column_2'] = df1['column_1'] + df2['column_1']`
gives the following result:

```
   column_1  column_2
0        10      13.0
1        20      25.0
2        30       NaN
3        40       NaN
4        50       NaN
5        60       NaN
6        70       NaN
7        80       NaN
8        90       NaN
9       100       NaN
```

So that:

- Elements with "overlapping" index values are summed.
- Other elements (with no corresponding index in *df2* are *NaN*.
- Because of the presence of *NaN* values, this column is coerced to *float*.

Alternative form of this instruction, using *.loc[...]* is:

```
df1['column_2'] = df1.loc[:, 'column_1'] + df2.loc[:, 'column_1']
```

It works on my computer either.

Or maybe you want to "multiply" (replicate) *df2* to the length of *df1*
before summing? If yes, run:

```
df1['column_2'] = df1.column_1 + df2.column_1.values.tolist() * 5
```

In this case *5* is the number of times *df2* should be "multiplied".

This time no index alignment takes place and the result is:

```
   column_1  column_2
0        10        13
1        20        25
2        30        33
3        40        45
4        50        53
5        60        65
6        70        73
7        80        85
8        90        93
9       100       105
```

Comment: Can I get an error if df_1 column has .int , and df_2 - float?

Comment: Please look for *Alternative form* in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) is applied on the df which have less number of records compared to the other, For example here y

**Subtraction:**

```
import pandas as pd
import re
x = pd.DataFrame([(100,200),(300,400),(100,111)], columns=['a','b'])
y = pd.DataFrame([(1,2),(3,4)], columns=['a','b'])
z= x - y.reindex_like(x).fillna(0)
```

**Addition**

```
import pandas as pd
import re
x = pd.DataFrame([(100,200),(300,400),(100,111)], columns=['a','b'])
y = pd.DataFrame([(1,2),(3,4)], columns=['a','b'])
z= x + y.reindex_like(x).fillna(0)
```

**Multiplication**

```
import pandas as pd
import re
x = pd.DataFrame([(100,200),(300,400),(100,111)], columns=['a','b'])
y = pd.DataFrame([(1,2),(3,4)], columns=['a','b'])
z= x * y.reindex_like(x).fillna(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that I can not make df_1['column_3] = df_1['column_1] + df_1['column_2] if df_1 is a slice from original dataframe df. So, I have solved my question by writing a function:

```
def new_column(dataframe):
    if dataframe['column']=='value_1':
   dataframe['new_column'] =(dataframe['column_1']
   - df_2[df_2['column']=='value_1']
      ['column_1'].values[0])
    else:
       dataframe['new_column'] =(dataframe['column_1']
       - df_2[df_2['column']=='value_2']
          ['column_1'].values[0])
    return dataframe
dataframe=df_1.apply(new_column,axis=1)
```