# Dataframe: Add values of two Daframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, sum

I have two Dataframes:

```
df1:
            A    B
Date
12/2020     1    0
13/2020     1    1


df2:
            A    B    C
Date
12/2020     0    0    1
13/2020     1    0    1
```

I want to add the values of df1 into df2 to get the following:

```
df3:
            A    B    C
Date
12/2020     1    0    1
13/2020     2    1    1
```

How can can I do this using something like pd.join or pd.merge? (I have two large dataframes)

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look here ?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106823/adding-two-pandas-dataframes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding two pandas dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106823/adding-two-pandas-dataframes)

Comment: if `add` does not work on your actual dataset but does work on this example, please update your question to have an example where add does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`add()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

```
>>> df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: That doesn't work. df2['C'] returns "nan" rather than "1". Also, the indices for df1 and df2 are not of the same length. I think something like .merge or .concat should work, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: @MathMan99 - You should provide the appropriate examples in your question. This should work regardless of of the your DataFrame sizes.

Answer (score 0):

in pandas there is a function

`x.add(y, fill_value=0)`

````
import pandas as pd

df1:
            A    B
Date
12/2020     1    0
13/2020     1    1


df2:
            A    B    C
Date
12/2020     0    0    1
13/2020     1    0    1

df3 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
Out: 
df3:
            A    B    C
Date
12/2020     1    0    1
13/2020     2    1    1
```

Try this
````

Comment: That doesn't work. df2['C'] returns "nan" rather than "1". Also, the indices for df1 and df2 are not of the same length. 
I think something like .merge or .concat should work, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: you should consider merge then

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as psql

df1 = 'Table1' #Insert dataframe
df2 = 'Table2' #Insert dataframe

#Create two dataframes to be joined on final dataframe
t1 = psql.sqldf('''
SELECT
   CONCAT(Date, A, B) AS Full1
   Date
   , A
   , B
FROM df1
''')

t2 = psql.sqldf('''
SELECT
   CONCAT(Date, A, B) Full2
   , Date
   , A
   , B
   , C
FROM df2
''')

#Create Full Dataframe
full_df = psql.df('''
SELECT
  tt.Full1
  , tt.Date
  , tt.A
  , tt.B
  , tt2.C
FROM t1 tt
LEFT JOIN t2 tt2 ON tt.Full1 = tt2.Full2
''')

#Create Final Dataframe
Final = psql.df('''
SELECT
   Date
   , A
   , B
   , C
FROM full_df
''')

#Save final result to csv
Final.to_csv(Index=False, 'file_name.csv')
```